# Override specific CSS selectors with Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I added Tailwind CSS to our company project. It's a 5-6 years old codebase and it's already using bootstrap CSS + custom bootstrap theme.

My tailwind JS config file looks like this:

[tailwind.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq4Uf.png)

I have added a custom prefix in order to avoid class conflict and also applied !important to all of the tailwind classes.

And I need to override the specificity of those selectors.
How could I achieve this using tailwind CSS?

[specific class selectors that need to be override](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwXfn.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Please dont't post images of code, just use the code tags available in the editor!

What you could do is overwrite those selectors manually in your tailwind css file which i guess is loaded AFTER the bootstrap file?

The order of css evaluation is key here.

> If both pieces of CSS have the same specificity (for example, they're both body{), then whichever gets called LAST will override the previous one. BUT, if something has higher specificity (a more specific selector), it will be used regardless of the order.